# Can't write variables to SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've attempted to make a simple PHP system that takes the user's login name, recipients name and message contents and write it to an SQL database.  I'm at the point where there are no errors at all, even after I send a message and the page refreshes. However no new entries appear in my SQL database (checking through phpMyAdmin). By the way all of this code is on the same page.

Starts off with a HTML form to gather data:

```
<form name="login" action="" method="POST">
<p>Recipient: <input type="text" name="recipient"/></p>
<p>Message: <input type="text" name="contents"/></p>
<input type="Submit" Name="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Then I setup the connection to the SQL database:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('host','username','password','database');
$sqlaction = 'INSERT INTO $userinbox (Sender, Message) VALUES ($email, $username)';
?>
```

Then the function that enters the information into the database:

```
<?php

session_start();

function message($link, $sqlaction)
{
$sender = $_SESSION['name'];
$recipient = strtolower($_POST['recipient']);
$contents = $_POST['contents'];

switch ($recipient) {
    case 'person1':
        $userinbox = 'person1';
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sqlaction);
        echo 'Message sent.';
        break;
    case 'person2':
        $userinbox = 'person2';
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sqlaction);
        echo 'Message sent.';
        break;
    case 'person3':
        $userinbox = 'person3';
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sqlaction);
        echo 'Message sent.';
        break;
    case 'person4':
        $userinbox = 'person4';
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sqlaction);
        echo 'Message sent.';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Current valid users are list of users';
}
}
```

And lastly, I call the function, passing the database connection variables:

```
message($link, $sqlaction);
```

But like I said, nothing appears in the database. I've spent 4 days trying to debug this and am on the verge of giving up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: tip: you don't need a separate table for each users inbox. Just create a table called inbox and add the field user_id, owner_id or similar. Then you can fetch the content of a spesific users inbox with everything stored in the same table. Reason is if you get 10.000 (100 really) users your db will look like a mess as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

You must use quotes for inserting strings like `"$email"` and not just `$email`. You must also escape table names with backticks i.e. this-> ` Your sql query will thus be :-

```
$sqlaction = "INSERT INTO `$userinbox` (Sender, Message) VALUES ('$email','$username')";
```

Note that for numbers (integers,double values,decimals etc) quotes are optional. Please see that you [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helps you.

Comment: I wasn't aware I had to use backticks, thankyou. However i'm still not recieving any input into my database. I'll play around with it and see if I can get it to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No errors. Tried 'error_reporing(E_ALL);' as said below but that just gives me a syntax error for undefined function.

When I try to submit a message I now get a blank entry in my database, but if I try to submit multiple messages I still only get one blank entry. Ill link you to my full code:

http://pastebin.com/a2VAx0Uc

Answer (score 0):

You don't have

```
$email and $username
```

defined in this code.
If you enable error reporing

```
error_reporing(E_ALL);
```

you will receive something like

```
Notice: undefined variable $email on line xxx in file.php
Notice: undefined variable $username on line xxx in file.php
```

Also the things @devaldcool said